# problem while starting grails application

Tags: grails, jvm

When i try to start my application it gives the error

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Any suggestions ???

Comment: Did you make any memory configuration of this app? What OS do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Got to Grails HOME/bin directory open startGrails file

Step 2: 
replace that if condtion for GRAILS_OPTS and out this line "set GRAILS_OPTS=-Xmx1024M -server"

without quotes

Step 3: Save

Answer (score 0):

- Open the Control Panel.
- Go to System.
- Go to Advanced Systems Properties.
- Then Environment Variables.
- In System Variables, click Add.
- New Variable Name: `_JAVA_OPTIONS`.
- New Variable Value: `-Xmx512M`.
- Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting the following on the command line solved it for me as I could not find that option in the startGrails file.
        set GRAILS_OPTS=-Xmx1024M -server
But i know i have to do that anytime i have memory issues.